# Wordpress limit footer menu to 4 links before starting a new list

Tags: php, wordpress

So i am trying to work out if it's at all possible to have a function that will display my page links in the footer like it currently does, BUT, after 4 links, create a new `ul` and populate another 4 links. And additionally limit the total over links shown to 8. So essentially on two lists allowed.

Is this possible? My code..

```
// the footer menu (should you choose to use one)
    function bones_footer_links() {
        // display the wp3 menu if available
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'container' => '',                              // remove nav container
            'container_class' => 'footer-links clearfix',   // class of container (should you choose to use it)
            'menu' => __( 'Footer Links', 'bonestheme' ),   // nav name
            'menu_class' => 'nav footer-nav clearfix',      // adding custom nav class
            'theme_location' => 'footer-links',             // where it's located in the theme
            'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
            'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
            'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
            'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
            'depth' => 4,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
            'fallback_cb' => 'bones_footer_links_fallback'  // fallback function
        ));
    } /* end bones footer link */

// this is the fallback for footer menu
function bones_footer_links_fallback() {
    wp_page_menu( array(
        'show_home' => true,
        'menu_class' => 'nav bottom-nav clearfix',      // adding custom nav class
        'include'     => '',
        'exclude'     => '',
        'echo'        => true,
        'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
        'link_after' => ''                             // after each link
    ) );
}
```

Which gives me:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Link</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-9 current_page_item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-46"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-42"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-44"><a href="#">Link</a>
</ul>
```

What i would like is after 4 links, a new `ul` like this:

```
<ul class="list_third">
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list_third">
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
</ul>
```

With a max of 8 links displayed in total.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this question has long been answered but I ran across it while trying to figure out something similar so I figured I'd post what I found.

While it isn't *exactly* what you were looking for it's possible to use CSS Column Count to come close. You can check out the same Fiddle I found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qUAT6/494/). This sure helped me so I figured I'd pass it along.

Cheers!
Daniel

```
div#multiColumn {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 20px;
```

}